Atkin-Lehner involution on the modular abelian varieties
Let $f$ be a CM modular forms with coefficients in the imaginary qudaratic field $K=Q(\sqrt{-3}))$ which correspond to an elliptic curve $E$ defined over $K$. Then Shimura constructed an abelian variety $A_f$ of dimension $2$ which is the quotient of the Jacobian $J_1(N)$ in the paper On the factors of the jacobian variety of a modular function field. In fact $A_f=J_1(N)/I_f$ where $I_f$ is the annihilator of $f$ in the Hecke algebra acting on $J_1(N)$. $A_f$ is defined over $Q$, but split to the product of $E$ and its complex conjugate $\bar{E}$ over $K$.  The cotangent space of $A_f$ is spaned by $f$ and $\bar{f}$. It is well-known that the Atkin-Lehner $W_N$ induces an automorphism of $X_1(N)$, then an automorphism of $J_1(N)$.  But $W_N$ interchange $f$ and $\bar{f}$ up to some scalars. I want to ask does $W_N$ induce automorphism of $A_f$ ? If so, how does it act on $A_f$,  interchanging $E$ and $\bar{E}$ ?

Since an algebraic number is zero if and only if any of its conjugates is zero, $I_f J_1$ is stable under $W_N$ and so indeed $W_N$ descends to an automorphism of $A_f$.
Now, the important thing to remember is that strictly speaking, the morphism
\begin{equation}
J_1\overset{T_p}\longrightarrow J_1
\end{equation}
does not induce
\begin{equation}
A_f\overset{a_p(f)}\longrightarrow A_f
\end{equation}
if one naturally interprets $a_p(f)$ has being multiplication by $a_p(f)$. It induces the morphism action of $T_p$, meaning that it is sensitive to the embedding of the field of coefficients of $f$ into $\mathbb C$ (this is why $A_f$ is properly attached not to $f$ but to the Galois conjugation orbit of $f$). Concretely, $a_p\varphi(f^\sigma)=a_p^\sigma\varphi(f^\sigma)$ if $\sigma$ is an embedding of the field of coefficients into $\mathbb C$ and $\varphi$ is an element of $J_1$ (lifted to a morphism on differential forms).
So $W_N$ interchanges $E$ and $\bar{E}$, as you thought.

@Oliver   Thank you very much for the answer, Olivier !  But how can you deduce $W_N$ interchanges $E$ and $\bar{E}$ from the above discussion ?

@yhb If $\varphi\in E$, $T_p\circ W_N\varphi(f)=T_p\varphi(f^{\sigma})=a^{\sigma}_p\varphi(f^{\sigma})$ and the only quotient of $J_1$ satisfying this is $\bar{E}$.

I see, thank you very much !
